# Update Docker image in ECS deploy

Tags: amazon-ecs

I deploy on AWS ECS a CloudFormation Stack, say `teststack`, via the command

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ./CloudFormationTemplate.yml --stack-name teststack --force-upload
```

My stack executes a certain Docker image, say `myname/myimage:latest`.

I want to deploy & update the stack via a pipeline (I'm using GitLab, but I guess this is not relevant for the question of interest here).

In this setting, I may modify my Docker image without touching the CloudFormation Template file; I then build & push the *new* image `myname/myimage:latest` to my registry; finally, I trigger a new pipeline, which launches again the command `aws cloudformation deploy ... --force-upload`.

When executing `aws cloudformation deploy ... --force-upload`, the pipeline returns `No changes to deploy. Stack stack-name is up to date`.

Evidently, since the stack is executing the `latest` tagged images, it returns that everything is up to date, whitout making a pull of the new `latest` image.

Is there a way to force AWS CloudFormation to pull new Docker images from my registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is using tags other than `latest` an option here? If so then you could tag the latest change you want to update let say `myname/myimage:0-0-1` and then update the container definition in your cloudformation template to use this new tag.

If you wish to continue using the `latest` tag you probably cant force the deployment by a cloudformation template update. In my project when I didnt want to change the tag I ended up doing the update using AWS CLI:

```
aws ecs update-service --service ${ecsService}  --cluster ${ecsCluster} --region ${region} --force-new-deployment
```

Comment: I hoped to be able to avoid the use of different tags than latest, since this would mean that I need to update the CloudFormation Template at each update of the stack just to change the image version. But I am thinking of a procedure that automates this procedure via some script...

Thanks for the suggestion, I am going to try it.

Comment: I opted for the tag solution, since it turns out quite simple to edit the CloudFormation Template inserting an environment variable. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I used this command but it does not do anything on the service. after running this, the service will be printed on the cli but nothing happens on the ECS side. no new revision. is it possible that the command does not show the error logs?